# OSError: [E053] Could not read config.cfg from C:\Users

Tags: spacy

I'm trying to run spaCY's lemmatizer on a text by running the command nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm", disable=["parser", "ner"]), but then I get the following error:

OSError: [E053] Could not read config.cfg from C:\Users.

I'm using spaCy version 3.2.1, and I also installed en-core-web-sm-2.2.0.

I also get this warning, but I'm not sure what it means:
UserWarning: [W094] Model 'en_core_web_sm' (2.2.0) specifies an under-constrained spaCy version requirement: >=2.2.0. This can lead to compatibility problems with older versions, or as new spaCy versions are released, because the model may say it's compatible when it's not. Consider changing the "spacy_version" in your meta.json to a version range, with a lower and upper pin. For example: >=3.2.1,<3.3.0.

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: Can we see the path you gave your program and the location of the file?

Answer (score 1):

A v2 spaCy model won't work with spaCy v3 - you need to update your model. Do this:

```
spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

The error could be easier to understand, but it's not a situation that comes up much - usually you'd have to upgrade from spaCy v2 to v3 but not upgrade your models for that to happen. Not sure how you got in that state.

Comment: That solved it, thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to help. I would appreciate it if you would accept or upvote my answer.